# Extract email and phone numbers from website using python and scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a list of thousands of websites and I would like to extract phone numbers and emails if available.
Possibly using `python + scrapy`

I found this one
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/scraping-websites-for-phone-numbers-and-emails-with-python-5557fcfa1596

but it looks like the package is not available anymore.
Any suggestions?
thanks!

Comment: Note that this does sound kind of spammy... could be wrong, though

Comment: I agree, I would say there is a 95% chance this is going to be used for spamming people... Don't really feel comfortable with helping here.

Comment: what do you mean? im not spamming anyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad question, so I cant answer it here completely.

Basically, you need to follow the following steps:

- First, scrape the website HTML using BS4 or Scrapy.
- Then use some regex to find emails, phone numbers

Also check this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/email-id-extractor-project-from-sites-in-scrapy-python/